# Multiobjective with single objectives that use distinct components of input vec? What does it mean for other components in input vec?

Tags: optimization

Multiobjective with single objectives that use distinct components of input vec? What does it mean for other components in input vec?

E.g.

$$\min (x_1,x_2)$$
$$x \in \mathbb{R}^2, x_1,x_2\geq0$$

Then if one solves this by one objective at a time, then one solves first $x_1$ then $x_2$. However, the input vector to this problem is $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

One could e.g. use initial guess $(0.5,0.5)$. Then the algorithm (e.g. minimize in scipy) might spit out $(0.0, 0.43)$. Since we were minimizing the first objective $x_1$, then the solution that we're interested in is $0.0$. However, the algorithm has clearly varied the second component as well, ending to $0.43$ due to some things in the algo.

Is the $0.43$ redundant? Why is it altered by e.g. scipy's minimize, even when the 1st objective doesn't contain it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It sounds like you are asking how to solve an optimization problem for a vector $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ when only a subset of those variables appear in the objective.  Yet, your example does not do that, it has $(x_1,x_2)$ appearing in both the objective and the constraints.  Anyway, it is common for the objective to only use a subset of the variables. You still need to solve for the entire vector of _all variables_ because the variables in the objective may be coupled with the other variables through the constraints.

Comment: I also do not know what you mean by "solving first $x_1$ but inputting $x=(x_1,x_2)$."  It is also not clear if you are trying to minimize or maximize your objective function $\min[x_1,x_2]$. I assume you are trying to minimize $\min[x_1,x_2]$ subject to the constraints, in which case the solutions are $(0,a)$ or $(a,0)$ with $a\geq 0$.